# Reset Button for highchart drilldown pie

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I have implemented drilldown pie chart using highcharts with 3 level drilldowns. I would like to add a reset button that brings back the pie chart to initial state if the user has drilldown to any level. is there a way to implement the reset?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some of the code you are using?

Comment: @Kingalione https://jsfiddle.net/xsznLmft/  this is the fiddle I am using and I want to implement one reset button and on clicking should reset all drilldown to the default state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drillUp` method:

```
document.getElementById('drillUp').addEventListener('click', function(){
  chart.drillUp();

  if(chart.series[0].name !== "Browsers"){
    chart.drillUp();
  }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0ju31xb8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#drillUp